# Nginx installation

Tags: software-installation, nginx

I got errors when execute the following command to get the Nginx service setup:

```
sudo wget -O init-deb.sh http://library.linode.com/assets/1139-init-deb.sh
```

The error is:

```
Resolving library.linode.com (library.linode.com)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘library.linode.com’
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error literally tells you what's wrong: `library.linode.com` is not available any more.

`nginx` can be either installed from the Ubuntu repositories (current version 1.6.2), or from the nginx repository. Current stable version is 1.8.0, current mainline is 1.9.5.

If 1.6.2 is fine for you, simply install with `apt`

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

[If want a more recent version, add the following repositories](http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html) to `sources.list` or create a new list in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

- For stable release

  ```
  deb http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/ codename nginx
  deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/ codename nginx
  ```
- For mainline

  ```
  deb http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu/ codename nginx
  deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu/ codename nginx
  ```

where you replace `codename` with your release, e.g `trusty`, `vivid`,...
Then update the package lists with `sudo apt-get update` and install nginx as described above.

Installing nginx from the repo will setup all the necessary scripts to start/stop the service.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get any package directly from a repository, you can use `wget` but on http://library.linode.com, there is no repository available.

So just update the resources using:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

If you want to add another repository use:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:repository_name
```

The, you can install the package simply by:

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

To check the status of nginx, do a:

```
sudo service nginx status
```